# How to refresh ListView content when popup windows is covering it in android?

Tags: android-listview, android

I have a list view which is backed by an ArrayAdapter which in turn is backed by a LinkedList (say var **list**) ... Now this list is modified by a background thread (NON - UI thread) whenever their is any change in it I call `notifyDatasetChanged()` in a Runnable (which is passed to `runOnUIThread()`)  of adapter and changes are reflected in the UI. No problem So far.

Now I have recently added a popup window in the app which is opened everytime user clicks on a row of the ListView not ( to mention it is customized based on the selected item).... Now my problem is if popup window is open (showing) and the `list` *changes* than their is a problem (desc below)...

How can I refresh the Adapter even when the PopupWindow is showing ??? Sometimes it works just  fine and sometimes I get...

**"A back ground thread changed the content of the adapter but the listview didn't receive any Notification"**

Comment: you can try setNotifyOnChange(true). Also have you tried notifyDataSetInvalidated()? Last you can try list.post(new Runnable(.. list.invalidate;||list.postinvalidate) . Any luck with those?

Comment: I think the list should also be update on the main UI thread in order to avoid the exception.

Comment: I am updating that by using runOnUiThread() @Luksprog